# How to decode a difficult citation in Wikipedia with "Historical Library"?

Tags: citations, wikipedia

> 89. Historical Library, V,39,1.

-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligures#cite_note-89

I came across this (bad?) citation while reading Wikipedia and I don't know how to follow it. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Note that the text refers to Diodorus who wrote a multi-volume work called Bibliotheca historica, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliotheca_historica.

Comment: I've [added a link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Diff/961398004) to that reference, crediting this comment. I also [redirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Historical_Library&redirect=no) "Historical Library" to Bibliotheca historica, [added](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Diff/961399484) a disambiguation hatnote to the latter, and created a [disambiguation page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_Library_(disambiguation)) or other uses of the term.

Answer (score 5):

It may help to look at the text that was added along with that footnote, in Sept. 2019:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ligures&diff=prev&oldid=914851412

You might wish to ask the user who added it, Shack76, by leaving a note on the bottom of their talk page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=User_talk:Shack76&action=edit&section=new

This user was active on this article within the last month, so I'd guess your chance of getting an answer is fairly good.

Yes, by the way, it is indeed a less than helpful citation; it would be good to improve it with more thorough information. I'd urge you to do so, once you've figured out what it is supposed to refer to. You will find the code for the footnote near the bottom of this edit window:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Ligures&action=edit&section=22
If you add any bibliographic information between the `<ref>` tag and the `</ref>` tag, and then click the "publish changes" button, it will be a big help to the next person who has a similar question. Don't worry too much about logging in, or about proper formatting; it's relatively easy for an experienced Wikipedian to tidy up the formatting, the hard part is tracking down the information you're seeking.

(Also note [a helpful comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149015/what-is-the-historical-library#comment396319_149015) from @mkennedy in the comments section.)